# How to calculate how many bites are "ON" in a binary number?

Tags: php, math, binary, bit

If i have 2 binary number representation: 127 and 128. How can i calculate that 127 have 7 bits "ON" and 128 have only 1 bit "ON"?

I did it like the following, but i think there's probably a better way (with math):

```
strlen(str_replace('0','',decbin(127))); // 7
strlen(str_replace('0','',decbin(128))); // 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you want is a [population count](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight).  The Wikipedia reference has some code, and for problems like this I always check [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) which is a great reference.

There are asm instructions for this on some machines, and both gcc and MSVC have compiler builtins.

For other languages, see:  [Population Count on RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Population_count)

Comment: it seems my method is much easier... I thought there would be a very simple mathematical method to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: I see, something like testing for powers of two via "!(n&(n-1))".  In C most people are concerned with the speed rather than the number of source characters, but it's easier in some languages (e.g. Python: bin(n).count("1"))